# Power Bi checking measures in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, ssas

Hello I want to check how measures are builded in Visual studio, Datasource of my Power Bi report is SSAS cube. How can I do that ?

I tried to run my visual studio New>project>Analysis services tabular model but idk what i should to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the "Import from Server (Tabular)" to create a new project importing the metadata from an existing SSAS Tabular Model.

[image]

You can also script the table in SSMS and see the DAX for its measures.